# dependencies with super classes

Tags: javascript, node.js, coffeescript

I'm updating this because while the question was answered, nothing related to the title was :)  How can I best manage dependencies with CoffeeScript classes?

Let's say I have a Super Class, 'utils.coffee':

```
fs = require 'fs'
# another bazillion libs

class Utils

  doThis: () ->
    console.log 'done!'

exports.Utils = Utils
```

In my Sub Class, I can easily call `doThis`. But I can't reference `fs` without getting the error: `ReferenceError: fs is not defined`. `myclass.coffee`:

```
{Utils} = require './utils.coffee'

class MyClass extends Utils

  doThat: () ->

    fs.readFile 'any_old_file', (error, fd) =>   
      buffer = fd.toString()

      # do stuff

exports.MyClass = MyClass
```

Than we run it:

```
{MyClass} = require('./myclass.coffee')
myclass = new MyClass()

myclass.doThis() # Cool!
myclass.doThat() # Not good
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not put `@` before your `trace` method. That makes it a class-level function instead of instance-level, along with all the other methods in that class.

```
trace: (className, method) ->
```

I would also recommend that you move your require calls out into the top-level scope, since there is no reason to call require every time your object is instantiated.

Instead of this:

```
@restler = require('restler')
@_ = require('underscore')
```

Just put this at the top:

```
restler = require 'restler'
_ = require 'underscore'
```

And the better Coffeescript way to do this:

```
Utils = require('./utils.coffee').Utils
```

is this:

```
{Utils} = require './utils.coffee'
```

Instead of this:

```
(if (results and results.length > 1) then results[1] else '')
```

Just do this:

```
if results?.length > 1 then results[1] else ''
```

Also I think this:

```
@buildKey: (args)
```

should probably be a splat, and could be rewritten like this:

```
buildKey: (args...)
    @debug(@getName(), 'buildKey', "arg: #{arg}") for arg in args
    return args.join ':'
```

#### Edit

I recommend that you familiarize yourself with CoffeeScript scoping rules, because that seems to be the source of most of your issues.

You have `@fs = fs` in your `Utils` class. This is equivalent to writing `Utils.fs = fs;` in JavaScript. Then you try to access this using `fs` in your `MyClass` class, which makes no sense, since fs is not in scope, as it is attached to Utils.

You would have to do `Utils.fs.readFile 'any_old_file', (error, fd) =>` if you want to access the `fs` reference you had previously saved.

Comment: Are you still having issues? Did this address the problems you were having?

Comment: I created an answer that shows what worked for me. I'm not sure why I can't get it to work without `fs = @fs`, like you state?

Comment: Normally you would just put the `require` call in both files, since you are using it in both and it's not much more work, but that's mostly up to preference. You are right though, if it is in only one file, then it will not be reachable from the other files.

Comment: That's what I figured. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Only referencing `fs` inside of the `utils.coffee` file, but outside of `Utils`, did not allow me to access it from another file. I had to set it like so:

```
fs = require 'fs'
# another bazillion libs

class Utils

  @fs = fs

  doThis: () ->
    console.log 'done!'

exports.Utils = Utils
```

Than, I simply accessed it like:

```
{Utils} = require './utils.coffee'

class MyClass extends Utils

  doThat: () ->

    Utils.fs.readFile 'any_old_file', (error, fd) =>   
      buffer = fd.toString()

      # do stuff

exports.MyClass = MyClass
```